# Ellipse: Known Distance from Focus to Far Side $(A+C)$ and $B$

Tags: conic-sections

I have a problem where I know the distance from one of the foci to the far side of the ellipse $(A+C)$ and I know $B$.  How would I find out what $A$ and $C$ are separately?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion.  $A$ is the semi-major axis.  $B$ is the semi-minor axis.  And $C$ is the distance from the center to each focus.

So I know the distance from one focus to the far end, which would be $C$ (distance from focus to center) + $A$ (semi-major axis).  But I don't know $C$ or $A$ individually.

Was trying to use the ellipse equation $C^2 = A^2-B^2$ but was unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: Not sure what $A,B,C$ are in this context. Is $A$ the distance between the foci and $C$ the distance between the focus and the boundary? What is $B$?

Comment: For example $((a+c) =9 ,b=3 ) \,( a=? c=?) ? $ If that is the case, $ a^2 + \sqrt{a^2-b^2}=9 $ is a quadratic in $a$  to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the  semi-major, semi-minor axes and linear  eccentricity of the [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), respectively, the $a$ and $c$ can be computed from the equations:
$$
a+c=r,\quad
a^2-c^2=b^2,
$$
where $r$ is the distance from one of the foci to the far side of the ellipse.

Substitution of either $a$ or $c$ from the first equation into the second one results in: 
$$a=\frac{r^2+b^2}{2r},\quad c=\frac{r^2-b^2}{2r}.
$$

Comment: What would $r$ be in the above equation?

Comment: @mls The explanation added.